# how to use a variable in a reguar expresion in apex?

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I am using the following to parse the data of the Telefon from my description field in the case in Inboundemailhandler.

```
Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile('(Telefon)\\W*\\d*');
Matcher m = urlPattern.matcher(body);
while (m.find()) system.debug(m.group());
```

But my Telefon is dynamic as in I am going to use a variable there. How do I build my regex in this case ? I know that in javascript you use regex constructor but I am not sure if we have something like this in apex.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried simple string concatenation to construct the expression passed to `Pattern.compile`?

Comment: It works, thank you and for some reason my dumb brain did not even think about this.